# python display datetime in differnet timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a timezone aware date time field in django called started on:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    started_on = models.DateTimeField()
    ended_on = models.DateTimeField()


    def started_on_tz(self):
        return self.started_on.astimezone(timezone(self.event.time_zone))
```

I want to show the startedon date in the events timezone.  It is currently displaying on the screen with my timezone.  I want to use the `started_on_tz` function to display the time in the timezone of the event.

For example:

I created a started on at 11am CST.
It prints on my web page as 9am PST.

How do I print 11am CST when I am currently in the PST time zone?

Comment: means, you need to display `started_on`  value as in DB ? right?

Comment: I don't think as the way it is stored in the db, becuase I believe that is stored as UTC.  I need the time in a different timezone.

Comment: Maybe you can make `started_on_tz` a property of the model (using the `@property` decorator). So you'll have 2 fields, `started_on` and `started_on_tz`.

Comment: I think, `astimezone()` method doing the same job as you looking for. It convert one timezone aware `datetime` object to anothor timezone. right ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the django timezone template tag a mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```